# IONIC-MQTT plugin doesn't call any method after MessageArrived | Angular 8 + ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, mqtt, angular8

hi guys i need an help, 
So: i've installed this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-mqtt

So this is my code is:

```
public TOPIC: string[] = ['Tagliavini/OvenStatus/#'];

  public MQTT_CONFIG: {
    host: string,
    port: number,
    clientId: string,
  } = {
    // host: "mqtt.micro-systems.it",
    // port: 9001,
    // clientId: "mqtt",
    host: "192.168.0.171",
    port: 9001,
    clientId: "mqtt",
  };

  ngOnInit() {

    this._mqttClient = this.mqttService.loadingMqtt(this.ConnectionLost, this.MessageArrived, this.TOPIC, this.MQTT_CONFIG);
  }



 MessageArrived(message) {
    console.log(message.payloadString) // this print the correct message
    this.elaborateMessageArrived(message); // this got error when call

  }

  elaborateMessageArrived(message){
    console.log("try to call me");
  }
```

So, the connection works better, but when i receive the payload from mqtt broker, the console log print the good message on console, like you see, but when i call

```
this.elaborareMessageArrived(message)
```

the error is:

> {errorCode: 5, errorMessage: "AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error
>   Message: this.ela…a function, Stack trace: No Error Stack Available",
>   reconnect: undefined, uri: "ws://192.168.0.171:9001/mqtt"} errorCode:
>   5 errorMessage: "AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message:
>   this.elaborateMessageArrived is not a function, Stack trace: No Error
>   Stack Available" reconnect: undefined uri:
>   "ws://192.168.0.171:9001/mqtt"
>   **proto**: Object

it's not possibile, the function exist, and works with other method, but when i call directly inside MessageArrived, i got this error, how can i solve ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. Without the internal code of `elaborateMessageArrived`, we can't help you.

Comment: There is no code inside

Comment: You were right. You did provide enough info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the function in the class context like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

this._mqttClient = this.mqttService.loadingMqtt(this.ConnectionLost, this.MessageArrived.bind(this), this.TOPIC, this.MQTT_CONFIG);
}`
```

This should solve your problem.

Some documentation for the `bind(this)` is here:

> The simplest use of bind() is to make a function that, no matter how
>   it is called, is called with a particular this value. A common mistake
>   for new JavaScript programmers is to extract a method from an object,
>   then to later call that function and expect it to use the original
>   object as its this (e.g. by using that method in callback-based code).
>   Without special care, however, the original object is usually lost.